# What is the grid size of my netCDF4 file? How to change the resolution from 100km to 25km?

Tags: python, resolution, qgis, netcdf4

I have downloaded tasmax global data from ESGF website. Here is the query to download the data from the website:
[Link to query](https://aims2.llnl.gov/search?project=CMIP6&activeFacets=%7B%22source_id%22%3A%22INM-CM4-8%22%2C%22institution_id%22%3A%22INM%22%2C%22activity_id%22%3A%22CMIP%22%2C%22nominal_resolution%22%3A%22100%20km%22%2C%22variant_label%22%3A%22r1i1p1f1%22%2C%22grid_label%22%3A%22gr1%22%2C%22table_id%22%3A%22day%22%2C%22frequency%22%3A%22day%22%2C%22variable_id%22%3A%22tasmax%22%2C%22cf_standard_name%22%3A%22air_temperature%22%2C%22experiment_id%22%3A%22historical%22%2C%22data_node%22%3A%22esgf-data1.llnl.gov%22%7D)

I am unfamilier with this type of data. Here are the details of the .nc files according to panoply:

```
netcdf file:/D:/Vandita/RRU/NSAB/Data/HistoricalTasmaxData/tasmax_day_INM-CM48_historical_r1i1p1f1_gr1_18500101-18991231.nc { 
dimensions:
time = UNLIMITED;   // (18250 currently)
lat = 120;
lon = 180;
bnds = 2;
variables:
double time(time=18250);
  :bounds = "time_bnds";
  :units = "days since 1850-1-1";
  :calendar = "365_day";
  :axis = "T";
  :long_name = "time";
  :standard_name = "time";
  :_ChunkSizes = 524288U; // uint

double time_bnds(time=18250, bnds=2);
  :_ChunkSizes = 1U, 2U; // uint

double lat(lat=120);
  :bounds = "lat_bnds";
  :units = "degrees_north";
  :axis = "Y";
  :long_name = "Latitude";
  :standard_name = "latitude";
  :_ChunkSizes = 120U; // uint

double lat_bnds(lat=120, bnds=2);
  :_ChunkSizes = 120U, 2U; // uint

double lon(lon=180);
  :bounds = "lon_bnds";
  :units = "degrees_east";
  :axis = "X";
  :long_name = "Longitude";
  :standard_name = "longitude";
  :_ChunkSizes = 180U; // uint

double lon_bnds(lon=180, bnds=2);
  :_ChunkSizes = 180U, 2U; // uint

double height;
  :units = "m";
  :axis = "Z";
  :positive = "up";
  :long_name = "height";
  :standard_name = "height";

float tasmax(time=18250, lat=120, lon=180);
  :standard_name = "air_temperature";
  :long_name = "Daily Maximum Near-Surface Air Temperature";
  :comment = "maximum near-surface (usually, 2 meter) air temperature (add cell_method attribute \'time: max\')";
  :units = "K";
  :original_name = "tasmax";
  :cell_methods = "area: mean time: maximum (interval: 1 day)";
  :cell_measures = "area: areacella";
  :history = "2019-05-29T14:48:10Z altered by CMOR: Treated scalar dimension: \'height\'.";
  :coordinates = "height";
  :missing_value = 1.0E20f; // float
  :_FillValue = 1.0E20f; // float
  :_ChunkSizes = 1U, 120U, 180U; // uint

  // global attributes:
  :Conventions = "CF-1.7 CMIP-6.2";
  :activity_id = "CMIP";
  :branch_method = "standard";
  :branch_time_in_child = 0.0; // double
  :branch_time_in_parent = 35405.0; // double
  :contact = "Evgeny Volodin (volodinev@gmail.com)";
  :creation_date = "2019-05-29T14:48:11Z";
  :data_specs_version = "01.00.29";
  :experiment = "all-forcing simulation of the recent past";
  :experiment_id = "historical";
  :external_variables = "areacella";
  :forcing_index = 1; // int
  :frequency = "day";
  :further_info_url = "https://furtherinfo.es-doc.org/CMIP6.INM.INM-CM4-8.historical.none.r1i1p1f1";
  :grid = "gs2x1.5";
  :grid_label = "gr1";
  :history = "2019-05-29T14:48:10Z ;rewrote data to be consistent with CMIP for variable clt found in table day.";
  :initialization_index = 1; // int
  :institution = "Institute for Numerical Mathematics, Russian Academy of Science, Moscow 119991, Russia";
  :institution_id = "INM";
  :mip_era = "CMIP6";
  :nominal_resolution = "100 km";
  :parent_activity_id = "CMIP";
  :parent_experiment_id = "piControl";
  :parent_mip_era = "CMIP6";
  :parent_source_id = "INM-CM4-8";
  :parent_time_units = "days since 1850-01-01";
  :parent_variant_label = "r1i1p1f1";
  :physics_index = 1; // int
  :product = "model-output";
  :realization_index = 1; // int
  :realm = "atmos";
  :references = "RJNAMM 2018, 367-374. DOI: 10.1515/rnam-2018-0032";
  :run_variant = "standard";
  :source = "INM-CM4-8 (2016): \naerosol: INM-AER1\natmos: INM-AM4-8 (2x1.5; 180 x 120 longitude/latitude; 21 levels; top level sigma = 0.01)\natmosChem: none\nland: INM-LND1\nlandIce: none\nocean: INM-OM5 (North Pole shifted to 60N, 90E; 360 x 318 longitude/latitude; 40 levels; sigma vertical coordinate)\nocnBgchem: none\nseaIce: INM-ICE1";
  :source_id = "INM-CM4-8";
  :source_type = "AOGCM AER";
  :sub_experiment = "none";
  :sub_experiment_id = "none";
  :table_id = "day";
  :table_info = "Creation Date:(20 February 2019) MD5:951084b632bd52c3f6224e495b1cb65e";
  :title = "INM-CM4-8 output prepared for CMIP6";
  :tracking_id = "hdl:21.14100/c4f81a54-faea-4644-9f50-037131f93209";
  :variable_id = "tasmax";
  :variant_label = "r1i1p1f1";
  :license = "CMIP6 model data produced by Lawrence Livermore PCMDI is licensed under a Creative Commons Attribution ShareAlike 4.0 International License (https://creativecommons.org/licenses). Consult https://pcmdi.llnl.gov/CMIP6/TermsOfUse for terms of use governing CMIP6 output, including citation requirements and proper acknowledgment. Further information about this data, including some limitations, can be found via the further_info_url (recorded as a global attribute in this file) and at https:///pcmdi.llnl.gov/. The data producers and data providers make no warranty, either express or implied, including, but not limited to, warranties of merchantability and fitness for a particular purpose. All liabilities arising from the supply of the information (including any liability arising in negligence) are excluded to the fullest extent permitted by law.";
  :cmor_version = "3.4.0";
}
```

I wish to reduce the resolution of the data from 100kms to 25kms. For that as I understand, I need to reduce the grid size somehow. I can be wrong. Use of python or QGIS would be helpful. Please advice.

Comment: You might want to look into xesmf or nctoolkit for regridding in python or CDO on the command line. In the meantime can you specify what grid you actually want to convert to? It sounds like you don’t know this and have provided sufficient info for someone to figure it out

Comment: @RobertWilson Sir in the file details, it says grid = "gs2x1.5". I think that might be the grid size. I think for 25km grid size is 0.25. However, I am not sure. In the end, I want to reduce the resolution from 100km to 25km.

Comment: You will need to show us what you have tried to solve the problem. Right now you are asking people to do all your work for you. That’s not the purpose of SO

Answer (score 0):

So you actually want to downscale to higher resolution your climate data. There are 3 ways for that (at least I know).

- Dynamical Downscaling
- Statistical Downscaling
- Interpolation

Interpolation is not actually real downscaling, just create new points wrt others. So the first two are not easy to do so you can search for them and can ask questions if you stuck at some point. Interpolation is much more easier especially with CDO. If you are using windows, check "Install Ubuntu on WSL2 on Windows" and install it by

```
sudo apt-get install cdo
```

then use the command

```
cdo remapbil,r1440x720 input.nc output.nc
```

Be careful there are some assumptions here, firstly the output is not actually 25km exactly, but 0.25 x 0.25 degree resolution, also remapbil uses bilinear interpolation, check the cdo documentation for other methods. Also probably there are methods to do it on qgis but CDO is much more easier for me.